# Curl-Java - Binding Package

Tags: java, curl

Has anyone used or have any experience of using the curl-java binding package.  I like curl because it supports NTLM proxy and thats very useful for what I need.  We have been using curl on the command line - but a binding would provide a better integration from an application server.  I've not been able to to find much in the way of user experience or patterns to use it.

Comment: never heard of the 'curl-java' package.  Please include a link.  What's wrong with HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Exception handling omitted:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new 
URL("https://www.example.com").openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.getOutputStream().write("LOGIN".getBytes("UTF-8"));
con.getInputStream();
```

To add basic authentication to this, Use :

`con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");` `//username:password base64 encoded`

Also You can try out the libcurl Java bindings: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/.

*Not a pure 100% Java solution but an option nonetheless. And It requires the C libcurl library..!!*